# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'term'

Tags: python, module, termcolor

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter notebook]

What is wrong here? I have python 3.8 but keep getting the error message above when I try importing 'colored' from the termcolor library. What should I try? Thank you.

Comment: try: from termcolor import colored

Comment: Reference on how to import https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/
Import like this:
from termcolor import colored

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

because it is not installed into anakonda's dependencies . (You may installed them into another Python dependencies).
at first determine where your python is located

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

you will gain something like  '/Users/some_user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
Then go to this direction

```
cd /Users/some_user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

and install missing package

```
./pip install term
```